# MongoDB Alphabetically Sorting

Tags: php, mongodb

In my MongoDB database one name field is available, in this name field data is stored in the format Aaa, Bbb, Ccc, Ddd. The first letter of the word is uppercase and remaining letter is lowercase. When I apply MongoDB sort query on this data. The sorting is not working properly

My code is like below one:-

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

 $pipeline = [
             [ '$match' => ['listingStatus' => 'Active'] ],
             [ '$sort' => ['listingParticipants.firstName' => -1]],
             [ '$group' => ['_id' => '$listingParticipants.email'] ],
             [ '$limit' => 10],
             [ '$skip' => 0],
         ];

        $aggregate = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command([
            'aggregate' => 'test_collection', 
            'pipeline' => $pipeline,
            'cursor' => new stdClass
         ]);

    $cursor = $manager->executeCommand('test_database', $aggregate);
```

I seen multiple solution on google, they use duplicate field with lower case and apply filter on that newly created field.

But in my project I don't create new field so please help me to solve this issue.